# Is there a way to group events in BigQuery SQL within 60 seconds of each other?

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I am having trouble trying to group events that occur within 60 seconds of the previous one. My current grouping is if it occurs within the same minute of the day, but that is giving me errors when a task happens at say 12:00:45 and the next one is at 12:01:35. I need them to be grouped together as the same job, but if it's 12:00:35 and the next is 12:01:45, they need to be a different job.

E.g current (job # just has to be a unique number, so I'm using unix_seconds/60 to give essentially unix_minutes at the moment):

```
SELECT time,
event,
TRUNC(UNIX_SECONDS(datetime)/60)) AS job
FROM table
```

```
datetime             event #  job #
-------------------  -------  -----
2021-07-06 12:00:35  event1   27091680
2021-07-06 12:00:55  event2   27091680
2021-07-06 12:01:43  event3   27091681
2021-07-06 12:03:08  event4   27091683
2021-07-06 12:04:01  event5   27091684
2021-07-06 12:05:02  event6   27091685
```

What I need:

```
datetime             event #  job #
-------------------  -------  -----
2021-07-06 12:00:35  event1   27091680
2021-07-06 12:00:55  event2   27091680
2021-07-06 12:01:43  event3   27091680
2021-07-06 12:03:08  event4   27091683
2021-07-06 12:04:01  event5   27091683
2021-07-06 12:05:02  event6   27091685
```

Comment: What if you have 10 rows that are 30 seconds apart?  Do they all get combined?

Comment: Yes, it needs to keep combining until there is a gap of 60 seconds or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select datetime, event, first_value(job) over(partition by grp order by datetime) job
from (
  select datetime, event, job, countif(gap) over(order by datetime) grp
  from (
    select *, datetime_diff(datetime, lag(datetime) over(order by datetime), second) > 60 gap
    from `project.dataset.table` 
  )
)
# order by datetime
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign groups to jobs that are within 60 seconds of another row in the group, then you can do the following:

- Determine where there is a gap of 60 seconds.
- Use a cumulative count of the gaps to assign the numbering.

In the context of your query:

```
select t.* except(datetime),
       sum(case when prev_datetime > datetime_add(datetime, interval -60 second) then 0 else 1
           end) over (order by datetime) as job
from (select t.*,
             lag(datetime) over (order by datetime) as prev_datetime
      from `table` t
     ) t;
```

This just assigns the last column sequentially, which seems consistent with your question.

Comment: Hi Gordon, apologies as it seems as though I must've incorrectly replicated your query in my initial testing. When the other answer worked first go I then accepted that one. I have just tested your answer again, and it does what I had asked for, although in my scenario, keeping the unixtime values was useful for me. Apologies again as I am new to here, and still learning the etiquette of the site.

Comment: @sbaker . . . Your question was pretty explicit that the unix time *is not important* ("(job # just has to be a unique number"), otherwise I would have put that in the answer.  A sequential number also has its benefits.